# How do I use Liquibase to import a stored procedure into MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, liquibase, changeset

I’m using Gradle 2.7, MySQL 5.5.46 and the Liquibase-Gradle 1.1.1 plugin.  I have a file with a stored procedure that looks like …

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS MyProc;

CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc(
 IN param1 VARCHAR(25),
 IN param2 VARCHAR(5),
 OUT outParam VARCHAR(2500))

BEGIN
…
END //
```

I’m able to import this file fine on a MySQL command line.  However, when I create this Liquibase changeset …

```
<changeSet id="create_my_stored_proc" author="davea">
    <sqlFile path="src/main/resources/scripts/my_stored_proc.sql" stripComments="true"/>
</changeSet>
```

And run it, I get the error

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER // 

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS MyProc’ at line 1
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:316)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:122)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1227)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1210)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:550)
    ... 126 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER // 

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS MyProc’ at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3847)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3783)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2447)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2594)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2499)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:844)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:748)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:314)
```

What do I need to do to correct this error?

**Edit:** I removed the “DELIMITER” line per the answer making my file look like …

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS MyProd;

CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc(
 IN param1 VARCHAR(25), 
 IN param2 VARCHAR(5),
 OUT outParam VARCHAR(2500))

BEGIN
…
END //
```

However, upon running the changeset I get this error …

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc(
 IN param1 VARCHAR(25), 
 IN param2 VAR' at line 3
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3847)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3783)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2447)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2594)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2499)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:844)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:748)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:314)
    ... 131 more
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Rather than specifying the delimiter in the file, you have to specify it in the change itself. To do that, remove the line containing `DELIMITER` from the sql file, and then alter the changeset so it looks like this:

```
<changeSet id="create_my_stored_proc" author="davea">
    <sqlFile endDelimiter="//" path="src/main/resources/scripts/my_stored_proc.sql" stripComments="true" />
</changeSet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I removed the DELIMTER line, per your suggestion and updated the changeset appropriately, but I'm still getting an error (included in my question).  Note that with the DELIMITER param I am able to import the file through the MySQL command line.

Comment: K, deleting the "DROP PROCEDURE" line as well allowed things to run properly.

Comment: The commands allowed by the MySQL command line vs what is allowed when sending commands through the JDBC driver are different, and it is not always clear which commands are allowed where. This is also true for other databases. What you can do with Oracle sqlplus command line is different than what is allowed when running plain SQL through the drivers.

Answer (score 8):

The line

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS MyProc;
```

generated error with your edited file, since it ends with a default delimeter (**;**), while the delimeter has been changed to **//**. You could keep this statement in the sqlFile using the changed delimeter **//**, i.e.:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS MyProc //
```

Answer (score 1):

For LiquiBase to create procedure You need to use xml create procedure, it will resolve Your problem. Also compile it and check if there is no error.

```
<changeSet id="create_my_stored_proc" author="davea">
<createProcedure path="src/main/resources/scripts/my_stored_proc.sql"/>
<sql>alter procedure MyProc compile;</sql>
<sql>call MyProc();</sql>
<changeSet id="create_my_stored_proc" author="davea">
```